# go module @latest found but does not contain package

Tags: go, module

I'm trying to make use of go module for the first time. What exactly the following error message is telling me?

```
module github.com/mkideal/cli@latest found (v0.2.2), but does not contain package github.com/mkideal/cli
module github.com/mkideal/cli@latest found (v0.2.2), but does not contain package github.com/mkideal/cli/ext
```

It happens during `go build`, whereas `go get` is just fine:

```
$ go get -v github.com/mkideal/cli
go: github.com/mkideal/cli upgrade => v0.2.2
```

but not `go get -v ./...`, which gave me the same error as above. My proxy setting looks OK:

```
$ go env | grep GOPROXY
GOPROXY="https://proxy.golang.org,direct"
```

Is it a problem of the go module/package I'm trying to use, or my own code's problem? -- I took a look at
https://github.com/mkideal/cli/blob/master/go.mod and it seems fine to me.

See the following update for details.

How can I overcome the situation? (I'm getting the same error message for my own repo as well)

**UPDATE:**

Here is the full log how I'm getting the above error:

- prepare `/tmp/015-file` from https://github.com/mkideal/cli/blob/master/_examples/015-file
- do `go mod init`
- then `go build`

Now the details:

```
$ cd /tmp/015-file

$ GO111MODULE=on

$ go mod init github.com/mkideal/cli/015-file
go: creating new go.mod: module github.com/mkideal/cli/015-file

$ cat go.mod 
module github.com/mkideal/cli/015-file

go 1.14

$ go build
go: finding module for package github.com/mkideal/cli
go: finding module for package github.com/mkideal/cli/ext
main.go:6:2: module github.com/mkideal/cli@latest found (v0.2.2), but does not contain package github.com/mkideal/cli
main.go:7:2: module github.com/mkideal/cli@latest found (v0.2.2), but does not contain package github.com/mkideal/cli/ext

$ go get -v github.com/mkideal/cli
go: github.com/mkideal/cli upgrade => v0.2.2

$ go get -v ./...
go: finding module for package github.com/mkideal/cli
go: finding module for package github.com/mkideal/cli/ext
go: finding module for package github.com/mkideal/cli
go: finding module for package github.com/mkideal/cli/ext
main.go:6:2: module github.com/mkideal/cli@latest found (v0.2.2), but does not contain package github.com/mkideal/cli
main.go:7:2: module github.com/mkideal/cli@latest found (v0.2.2), but does not contain package github.com/mkideal/cli/ext

$ go version
go version go1.14.1 linux/amd64
```

Comment: What command produces the error, `go build`? or a simple `go get github.com/mkideal/cli`? (P.S.no need for the `@latest` - it is implied)

Comment: Also show what `go env` reports - maybe a rogue proxy setting?

Comment: For anyone who want to give it a try -- https://github.com/mkideal/cli/blob/master/_examples/015-file/main.go

Comment: @xpt It works well on my machine. What's your go version and the go.mod?

Comment: See my updated OP @hyz

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Cleaning up Golang caches should do the job:

```
go clean -cache
go clean -modcache
```

For more info on how this command works, use `go help clean`.
If you have similar problems with your test environment, run `go clean -testcache`.

Comment: It didn't worked for me, I wrote my solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77547868/12972198

Answer (score 48):

Try clearing cache:
`go clean -modcache`

For more info on how this command works, use `go help clean`

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. Consider making a comment instead of an answer because this does not give any information asked by the question, but rather a tips or additional things OP can do.

Comment: Go clean worked for me but took too long and removed all downloaded packages. I wish there was another solution

Comment: I faced this as well, the solution was to add replace directives after the require directive, to use a version that has your package. ie
`replace your_packge_name => your_package_name v1.2.3`

Answer (score 8):

In my case cleaning cache didn't help.
Running `go install` in a project root printed `no Go files in ...` and that was the root cause, in the same time running `go install gitlab.com/....` printed info about a missing package.

What had to be done was creating a go file in a project root directory with `main` function.

Answer (score 5):

In my case, go.mod files were under src, after moving the go.mod file into one level up, then it works

Refer the Samples below,

**directory structure when "package not found" error**

```
dir1/src/
   main.go
   go.mod
   go.sum
```

**directory structure after fix**

```
dir1/
   go.mod
   go.sum
   src/
     main.go
```

Comment: I ran into the same problem, where the problem was the thing I was try to import had a difference between the go module path (in go.mod) and the actual directory structure in the GitHub repo.

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar problem. In my case the `package` name in `go.mod` was not matching the name of the folder it resided in.

Answer (score 4):

- Update to `go version go1.14.3 linux/amd64`
- Clear go module cache

don't know which one solved the problem (or both), now AOK.

Comment: go clean -modcache  is  key result

Answer (score 3):

I had the same error, but in my case I was attempting to import a module that made available only resource files, and no go pkgs. Adding an empty go file in the module with a package declaration solved it.

Answer (score 2):

I was having this issue with https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/vmware-labs/yaml-jsonpath/pkg/yamlpath because I was trying to it as `yamlpath "github.com/vmware-labs/yaml-jsonpath`

I was getting errors like

```
go: finding module for package github.com/vmware-labs/yaml-jsonpath
example.com/template-test/poc imports
        github.com/vmware-labs/yaml-jsonpath: module github.com/vmware-labs/yaml-jsonpath@latest found (v0.3.2), but does not contain package github.com/vmware-labs/yaml-jsonpath
```

```
no required module provides package github.com/vmware-labs/yaml-jsonpath; to add it:
        go get github.com/vmware-labs/yaml-jsonpath
```

[@Martin Meli's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75486611/2125837) helped me.

I needed to import `github.com/vmware-labs/yaml-jsonpath/pkg/yamlpath` instead. That resolved the issue.

```
$ go build
$ #...
$ go get github.com/vmware-labs/yaml-jsonpath/pkg/yamlpath@v0.3.2
go: downloading github.com/dprotaso/go-yit v0.0.0-20191028211022-135eb7262960
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same error but with a different scenario and solution.

**Scenario:** I was getting this error:

```bash
go.opentelemetry.io/otel/semconv: module go.opentelemetry.io/otel@latest found (v1.13.0), but does not contain package go.opentelemetry.io/otel/semconv
```

**Reason:** It was because `go.opentelemetry.io/otel/semconv` existed in old version of `go.opentelemetry.io/otel` but it doesn't now.

**Solution:** I should've looked for a place which I wrongly Imported `go.opentelemetry.io/otel/semconv` instead of `go.opentelemetry.io/otel/semconv/vX.Y.Z`

Replacing the imported package fixes the problem in many cases but my problem was a little bit deeper,

I hadn't imported `go.opentelemetry.io/otel/semconv` directly but one of my deprecated third-party packages (Otel Jaeger) did, so I removed the third-party package and this fixed my issue.

---

TL;DR: I recommend people facing this issue reconsider using deprecated packages and also have a look if they've imported the correct packages.