# go: module found but does not contain package

Tags: go, module, package

I am trying to install the net package for go but get "does not contain package error".

Terminal screenshot:

[image]

I have consulted: [go module @latest found but does not contain package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62974985/go-module-latest-found-but-does-not-contain-package) but none of the solutions seem to work for me.

I am using go version `go1.18.5 linux/amd64`

Comment: Use `go install` for "installable" packages, i.e. **executable** packages, i.e. packages called `main`.

Comment: `golang.org/x/net` is, as you already know, *not* a package. Instead it's a repo containing multiple packages. The repo's [readme](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/net#section-readme) clearly shows what you should do to *get* those packages from that repo.

Comment: @mkopriva tried it with golang.org/x/net/proxy (the module I want) and still get the same issue

Comment: @mkopriva I have no go.mod file, so I cant use this command

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to initialize your module with `go mod init` in the project root directory

For local codebase

```
go mod init test
```

OR for **hosted codebase** e.g. github repo: *test*, github user: *radiant*

```
go mod init github.com/radiant/test
```

It will produce a `go.mod` file.

Then you can get the required package as:

```
go get golang.org/x/net
go mod tidy
```

Then import and use the net packages.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
go get -u golang.org/x/net
```

go install used for executable packages

Comment: I get this error message: go: go.mod file not found in current directory or any parent directory.

Comment: go mod init test.me/test_package/

Comment: https://go.dev/doc/tutorial/create-module

Comment: After go mod init, you maybe need go mod tidy

Comment: malformed module path "home/barry/test" empty path element